# key detection in active window of eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, key, actionlistener

I am developing a simple plugin for eclipse where I want to detect what the user (who is opening a project file and typing in an editor) is typing. So far I have got the current workbench, currently active editor and the property changes made to the editor using the `IPropertyListener`; but I am repeatedly failing to detect whether any key is pressed or not.

the code:

```
       IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
       IWorkbenchWindow win = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
       IWorkbenchPage page = win.getActivePage();
       System.out.println
               ("Yeah the editor is visible..." + page.isEditorAreaVisible() + "with ..." +     page.toString() );
       IEditorPart theEditor =  page.getActiveEditor() ;  

       IPropertyListener myPropL = new IPropertyListener() 
       {


        @Override
        public void propertyChanged(Object arg0, int arg1) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            System.out.println("This is : " + arg0.toString()   );

        }
    };


        theEditor.addPropertyListener(myPropL);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? I can't help you with listening to all keys, but probably there's other way.

Comment: I fixed it by myself. 

This is the solution : 
1. get the IDocumentListener 
   using IDocumentListener lr = new IDocumentListener() 

2. Override the documentChanged(DocumentEvent arg0) and use the 
   arg0 parameter to get the typed text and the typed key using  arg0.offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by myself.

This is the solution :

1. get the IDocumentListener using `IDocumentListener lr = new IDocumentListener()`
2. Override the `documentChanged(DocumentEvent arg0)` and use the arg0 parameter to get the typed text and the typed key using arg0.offset.

For further questions happy to help :-)